# Run-time error 9 for adding vlookup in a loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, runtime-error, vlookup

I use the following code to add a vlookup function to the certain cell in a loop. After a point, I get run-time 9 or 1004. I cannot handle the issue by myself. Thank you very much in advance for your support.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim V As Range
    Dim cell1 As Range
    Dim isect1 As Range
    Set V = Range("D4:D29")
    Set isect1 = Intersect(Target, V)
    If isect1 Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        For Each cell1 In isect1
            If cell1.Value <> "" Then
                cell1.Offset(0, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell1, Workbooks("KV_ENVANTER.xlsm").Sheets("sheet3").Range("D2:E9"), 2, False)
            ElseIf IsEmpty(cell1.Value) = True Then
                cell1.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
            End If
        Next cell1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: On which line are you getting the error? I can't find anything inherently incorrect atm.

Comment: On this line: cell1.Offset(0, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell1, Workbooks("KV_ENVANTER.xlsm").Sheets("sheet3").Range("D2:E9"), 2, False)

Comment: Other than either your workbook or sheet name having a spelling error, I don't know what else could be wrong.

Comment: When it errors is there actually a match?

Comment: And is the other workbook open?

Comment: It often gives errors when running on someone else's computer. When it gives an error, it doesn't match.

Comment: Yes, there was a spelling error, because i was accidentally trying to run in the copy of the original workbook then the name naturally changed. But why it gives error on someone else's computer without name change? If it is because of name, can the code be modified without using worksheet name?

Comment: WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell1, ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet3").Range("D2:E9"), 2, False)

Comment: It gives an error because the file name has changed on other computers. Thank you all for your contribution. You brought me closer to the solution